# how to know the max depth, min_samples_leaf of decision trees of already existing random forest regression model in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, random-forest, prediction

I am using random forest regression model for prediction and I am running through a problem related to the accuracy and MAPE they give me weird values however, the MSE, and RMSE still give me apparently decent results. I have tried the following code:

```
rf_datas_temp = rf_datas.copy()

rf_datas_temp1 = rf_datas_temp.sample(frac=1, replace=False).reset_index(drop=True)
x = rf_datas_temp1[RFR_Col_2 ]   
y = rf_datas_temp1['ΔR'].values  # Target

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

# # train RF

x_train = x_train.fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)
x_test = x_test.fillna(0).reset_index(drop=True)

y_train[np.isnan(y_train)] = 0
y_test[np.isnan(y_test)] = 0 

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=200, random_state=42)
rf.fit(x_train, y_train)

# # Predict with RF and evaluate

prediction = rf.predict(x_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, prediction)
rmse = mse**.5
abs_diff = np.array(np.abs((y_test - prediction)/y_test))
abs_diff = abs_diff[~np.isinf(abs_diff)]

mape = np.nanmean(abs_diff)*100
accuracy = 100 - mape

print(mse,rmse,mape, accuracy)
print("Training Accuracy = ", rf.score(x_train, y_train))
print("Test Accuracy = ", rf.score(x_test, y_test))
```

and I have got the following results

`MSE = 0.016, RMSE = 0.1280 , MAPE = 183 accuracy = -83.26`

`Training Accuracy = 0.90, Test Accuracy = 0.195`

Is there  a method to know the values of parameters like `max tree depth`,  `min_samples_leaf , etc in order to tune them for better results?

Also, I would like to know if my model overfits or not according to the previous results.

Answer (score 1):

1. To retrieve all the hyperparameters of an already trained `RandomForestRegressor` in scikit-learn, you can utilize the `get_params` method. This will provide you with a dictionary containing all the hyperparameters and their respective values.

```py
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rf = RandomForestRegressor()  # For demonstration purposes. Substitute with your trained model.
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)      # For demonstration purposes.

# Fetch all parameters
params = rf.get_params()

# Output each parameter and its corresponding value
for key, value in params.items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```

2. There is no a method to know the values of parameters. You give numbers based on your experience. There are several methods to find the best parameters.Some of these are GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV.But in these techniques, the parameters that will be called are shaped according to the secret experiences
3. I guess, you handle the regression problem so what is the accuracy ? but the training accuracy (0.90) is much higher than the test accuracy (0.195), which indicates potential overfitting.

Comment: thank you for your answers, regarding the accuracy here, it is represented by the 100% - MAPE.